# Store and Retrieve user defined objects to IsolatedStorage in WPF (Devexpress) to display them in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, devexpress, isolatedstorage

I have the following Class:

```
public partial class ContentSet{

        [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private System.Nullable<int> IdField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string NameField;

        [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
            get {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.Nullable<int> Id {
            get {
                return this.IdField;
            }
            set {
                if ((this.IdField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.IdField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Name {
            get {
                return this.NameField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.NameField, value) != true)) {
                    this.NameField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Which, I am using :

```
public ContentSet SelectedContentSet
{
get{return selectedContentSet;}
set{selectedContentSet = value;}
}
```

This particular Item, I am using to bind the SelectedItem for the below ComboBox:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="ContentSetCombobox" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" IncrementalFiltering="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ContentSetList}" DisplayMember="Name" AllowUpdateTwoWayBoundPropertiesOnSynchronization="False"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContentSet,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                                            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
                                                <dxe:ComboBoxStyleSettings/>
                                            </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
                                        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

So, when a value is returned for:
SelectedContentSet = //Value
That value is bound to the ComboBox SelectedItem.

Now, once a value is selected for the ComboBox, I want that value to be stored in a IsolatedStorage so that even if I close the application, upon reopening it, I can retrieve the saved information and display it again.

For storing the details, I am using:

```
//First Get the 'User-Scoped' storage information location reference in the assembly
                    IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetMachineStoreForAssembly();
                    //Create a stream writer object to write content in the location
                    StreamWriter srWriter = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("isotest", FileMode.Create, isolatedStorage));
                    //check if the Application property collection contains any values
                    if (App.Current.Properties[0] != null)
                    {
                        srWriter.Write(save);
                    }

                    srWriter.Flush();
                    srWriter.Close();
```

And for retrieving it back:

```
//First get the 'User-Scoped' storage information location refernce in the assembly
                        IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetMachineStoreForAssembly();
                        //Create a stream reader object to read content from the created isolation location
                        StreamReader srReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("isotest", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isolatedStorage));
                        {//Open the Isolated Storage
                            if (srReader==null)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("No Data Stored");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                while(!srReader.EndOfStream)
                                {
                                    App.Current.Properties[0] = srReader.ReadLine();
                                }
                            }
                            srReader.Close();
                        }
```

But I was unable to retrieve the values.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You know that IsolatedStore also stores file(s), similar to user-scope settings?

Comment: I do not know that. Can you provide me some content regarding that?

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage) for an overview, especially [Isolated Storage Locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage#isolated_storage_locations).

Comment: I followed it through, but I couldn't find any way to save entire class object into the IsolatedStorage and retrieve it back...